# Python - indentation error

Tags: python, indentationerror

I've started learning python for future use in QGIS and using Ubuntu, installed with Python 3. I'm doing the tutorials from the great book for newbies "A byte of python". I'm having troubles running some python-programs from the chapter "Control overflow", all with the same error. For example running this file of mine, "while.py" :

Input:

```
number = 23
running = True
while running:
guess = int(input('Enter an integer : '))
if guess == number:
print('Congratulations, you guessed it.')
running = False # this causes the while loop to stop
elif guess < number:
print('No, it is a little higher than that.')
else:
print('No, it is a little lower than that.')
else:
print('The while loop is over.')
# Do anything else you want to do here
```

Output(the error):

```
  File "if.py", line 4
    print('Congratulations, you guessed it.') # New block starts here
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
morck@morck-N150-N210-N220:~/dokumenter$ python3 while.py
  File "while.py", line 4
    guess = int(input('Enter an integer :'))
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
morck@morck-N150-N210-N220:~/dokumenter$
```

Where the right output according to the tutorial should have been:

```
$ python3 while.py
Enter an integer : 50
No, it is a little lower than that.
Enter an integer : 22
No, it is a little higher than that.
Enter an integer : 23
Congratulations, you guessed it.
The while loop is over.
Done
```

Can't figure out what causes the error and need some insight understanding this.

Comment: Indentation is part of the syntax in Python. Rather than `{` curly braces `}` or `Begin`/`End` keywords, Python uses indented blocks to structure code hierarchically. Any decent Python intro material should explain this as it is one of the most prominent language syntax features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to indent any code inside a block. A block is something that follows a line ending with `:`

```
number = 23
running = True
while running:
    guess = int(input('Enter an integer : '))
    if guess == number:
        print('Congratulations, you guessed it.')
        running = False # this causes the while loop to stop
    elif guess < number:
        print('No, it is a little higher than that.')
    else:
        print('No, it is a little lower than that.')
else:
    print('The while loop is over.')
```

This should have been covered in the book.